# Infinite loop trying to create a Custom View from xib in swift 5 using Xcode 11 beta

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5

I want to create a reusable UI framework in swift 5 using Xcode 11 beta. My Framework class is:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
open class MyFramework: UIView {

    var view: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var helloLabel: UILabel!

    var nibName: String = "MyFramework"

    public override init(frame: CGRect) {
     // For use in code
      super.init(frame: frame)
      setUpView()
    }

    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override public func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        setUpView()
    }

    private func setUpView() {

        if let contentView = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(self.nibName, owner: self, options: nil)?.first as? UIView {
            contentView.frame = self.bounds
            self.addSubview(contentView)
            contentView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
            helloLabel.text = ""
        }
    }

     public func set(helloLabel text: String) {
        self.helloLabel.text = text
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
    }
}
```

In my xib file I have just added one label.

When I use this framework in another project I am getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS error because of setUpView() called infinite time.

```
import MyFramework

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let view = MyFramework()
        view.set(helloLabel: "Hello World!!!!")
    }
}
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Bundle.main.loadNibNamed` in your `setUpView` method, the view is loaded from nib, and therefore `awakeFromNib` is called, which in turn calls `setUpView`, and leading to the infinite loop.

I'm not sure why you need to load only the content view from nib and then add it as a subview, instead of loading your entire custom view from the nib. But if you insist so, at least, after loading the content view from nib, set an instance variable say maybe `contentView: View?` to the loaded content view. And add a check in your `setUpView`, where if the content view is not nil, just return.

And the nib that you load in your `setUpView`, since it's for your content view only, should definitely not be `self.nib`

Answer (score 0):

Just move your setupView to init(coder: NSCoder) method